# How to use ajax in ofbiz Forms?

Tags: ajax, forms, drop-down-menu, ofbiz

I'm using drop-down tag but I want to update another fields after selected an option in this. I'm using it in Forms. I know we can using ajax to submit and update but in ftl, I can't find which attribute of field or drop-down can help ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to resolve this problem. We will use js to post, send a request and get data with json format.
Example:

- my Forms:

  ```html
  <field name="firstFieldId">
              <drop-down allow-empty="false">
                  <list-options key-name="firstFieldId" list-name="listOptions1" description="${des1}"/>
              </drop-down>
          </field>
          <field name="secondFieldId">
              <drop-down allow-empty="false">
                  <list-options key-name="secondFieldId" list-name="listOptions" description="${des2}"/>
              </drop-down>
          </field>
  ```

  - create test.js:

  ```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("select[name='firstFieldId']").change(function(){
    update($(this).val());
   });
  });
  function update(id) {
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'myRequest',
          type: "POST",
          data:{
           firstFieldId: id
          },
          success: function(res) {
           var data = res.listOptions;
              renderHtml(data);
          }
      });
  }
  function renderHtml(data){
   var y = "";
   for (var x in data){
    y += "<option value='" + data[x].secondFieldId + "'>";
    y += data[x].des2 + "</option>";
   }
   $("select[name='secondFieldId']").html(y);
  }
  ```
- Screens:

  ```html
  <actions>
   <set field="layoutSettings.javaScripts[+0]" value="/delys/images/js/logistics.js" global="true"/>
  </actions>
  ```
- Controller.xml :

  ```html
  <request-map uri="myRequest">
    <security auth="true" https="true"/>
    <event type="service" invoke="myService"></event>
    <response name="success" type="request" value="json"></response>
  </request-map>
  ```

  In myService returns listOptions will parse to json format.
- json request in common-controller.xml:

  ```html
  <request-map uri="json">
          <security direct-request="false"/>
          <event type="java" path="org.ofbiz.common.CommonEvents" invoke="jsonResponseFromRequestAttributes"/>
          <response name="success" type="none"/>
  </request-map>
  ```

  This is my way, thanks!